# Collect Responses From Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am quite new to Google Scripts and attempting to learn, but documentation is either conflicting, non-existent, or not working for me.

The goal is to have a script that collects responses from a Google Form and sends emails based on one of the user input fields (a drop down box where the user can select their location).  Problem being that I cannot retrieve the Form responses.  I am receiving an error that the "getItemResponses();" is not a function.  How do I get responses from a Form?  All the other parts I have figured out.

Flow - I have setup a trigger by going to Edit -> Current projects' triggers -> created a new trigger that on submit it runs my function. What is supposed to happen is (later in the script) sendMail sends a mail message as me to the var "respondent".  However, I receive the error "getItemResponses();" is not a function when just attempting to run from the script editor and filling out a test form submissions (via email on the latter).

Thank you for any help in advance.  Please note, again, I'm new at the Google Scripts.

```
function sendEmails(e) {
  // Get active form and responses
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // Assign responses to variables
  var respondent = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var district = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var urgency = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var type = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var topic = itemResponses[4].getResponse();

  // TAM email address.  Used in sendTo field later
  var sendTo = "person@email.com";

  MailApp.sendEmail(sendTo,"subject","message body");

  if(type == "Option 1") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(respondent,"subject","message body");
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that providing your current script and the flow for replicating your issue will help users think of the solution.

Comment: function sendEmails(e) {
  // Get active form and responses
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses.getItemResponses();
  
  // Assign responses to variables
  var respondent = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var district = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var urgency = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var type = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  var topic = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
}

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to add a code block...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you add the script in your question? Because it is difficult to see the script in the comment. You can edit your question by [the edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60806083/edit). And can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? For example, how do you run the function `sendEmails(e)` ?

Comment: Added the code!  So the other part of the script just has a bunch of school district and employee info/emails I'd rather not take the time to cutout.  The biggest issue is just that I'm receiving "getItemResponses();" is not a function so I cannot pull the users email and other information that the future of the script will rely on (and works) - tested it with a Google Sheet

Comment: I presume you also have a sheet collecting the responses? Is there any particular reason why you are doing this in the form rather than on a sheet where there are multiple add-ons that can be used to email responses?

Comment: I do have a sheet linked to it yes.  My employers have blocked all none Google made addons, which basically eliminates the ability for addons.  I have a programming/networking background so I figured it would be just as easy to spin something up on my own - as more trustworthy since I made it and know what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

`form.getResponses()` returns an array of `FormResponse`, as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses()). An array of responses does not have a method called `getItemResponses()` and this is the reason you code is failing. What you're doing right now is getting all the responses corresponding to a form, and not the one that was just submitted.

You should use the method [getItemResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getItemResponses()) from a single [FormResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response) instead.

#### Solution:

Assuming that:

- You want the script to run (and, if the conditions are met, send an email) every time the form is submitted.
- You have installed an [onFormSubmit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()), connected to your form.

If that's the case, you should be using the trigger [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1) to get the `FormResponse`. You should replace this:

```js
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var itemResponses = formResponses.getItemResponses();
```

With this:

```js
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
```

#### Update:

Your form does not have 5 items, but 4. First item is actually the **respondent email**, and as such, it has to be retrieved via [FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail()). Because of this, `itemResponses` only gets to index 3, not to 4, and `itemResponses[4]` is undefined. That's the reason behind your new error. You should do this instead:

```js
  var respondent = formResponse.getRespondentEmail();
  var district = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var urgency = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  var type = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  var topic = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects: Form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_1)
- [Form.getResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getResponses())
- [FormResponse.getRespondentEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getRespondentEmail())

Comment: Thank you very much this makes sense!  I have made the changes per your recommendation and that overcame the issue, but now opened up a different issue.  I received an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined"

error is caused by line 8 of my original code - it seems the array objects are undefined?
(attempting to add code) 
'var respondent = itemResponses[0].getResponse();'

Comment: @GabrielCirtwell Have you tried logging `itemResponses`? What are you getting? Also, could you share a sanitized copy of the files you're working (free of sensitive information), so that I can try to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: @lamblichus.  I edited my post to provide all the code (realized a lot of it was comments that I was trying to work with other people on so I just removed the unnecessary comments and sanitized the little that needed to be done).  I have not tried logging yet, but will do so now.  Thank you for the response and I will get back to you asap

Comment: @GabrielCirtwell I meant sharing the form itself. That's where the issue must be. You installed an `onFormSubmit` trigger attached to this form, and not to a spreadsheet where the form sends the responses to, right? If you can share it, I'll try to reproduce your behaviour, and hopefully, find out what's failing.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13DXbjts1rLNyJFLCFM5FnW-ndikAHm0HewHlMO8eaww/edit?usp=sharing

I set it to anyone with the link can edit.

Comment: @GabrielCirtwell I updated my answer based on the information you provided. Please let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That was it!  Not sure why my form wasn't working the first time - made a new form, copy/pasted the original code and it works now!

Thank you!  Marking your answer as correct now

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do what you want to do from the form its self it will be difficult as a beginner since as you noticed there aren't many example scripts to work off.

It will be much easier to do this from the responses sheet and there are plenty of examples around for processing form data from a spreadsheet.

The example below is a simple (untested) script to send a reply on form submission.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();    
  var respSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var rowIndx = e.range.getRow();

  var formData = respSheet.getRange(rowIndx, 1, 1, respSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var respondent = formData[0].getResponse();
  var district = formData[1].getResponse();
  var urgency = formData[2].getResponse();
  var type = formData[3].getResponse();
  var topic = formData[4].getResponse();

  MailApp.sendEmail(respondent, district + ' ' + topic, "Your reply was recieved and is being processed");

  respSheet.getRange(rowIndx, 5).setValue('Email send to ' + respondent);

}
```